# how to prevent logging warning in a .get(true , false) statement to appear even though it is true and not false

Tags: python-3.7

I am making an application which rarely uses the terminal for output. So, I found that the logging library was a great way to help debug faulty code as supposed to the print statement.

But, for this code, specifically the .get() statement at the bottom...

```
def process_variables(self, argument):
    data = pd.read_excel(self.url, sheet_name=self.sheet)
    data = pd.concat([data.iloc[2:102], data.iloc[107:157]]).reset_index()
    fb = data.loc[0:99, :].reset_index()
    nfb = data.loc[100:155, :].reset_index()

    return {'fb': data.loc[0:99, :].reset_index(),
            'nfb': data.loc[100:155, :].reset_index(),

            'bi': data.loc[np.where(data['Unnamed: 24'] != ' ')],
            'uni': data.loc[np.where(data['Unnamed: 25'] != ' ')],

            'fb_bi': fb.loc[np.where(fb['Unnamed: 24'] != ' ')],
            'fb_uni': fb.loc[np.where(fb['Unnamed: 25'] != ' ')],

            'nfb_bi': nfb.loc[np.where(nfb['Unnamed: 24'] != ' ')],
            'nfb_uni': nfb.loc[np.where(nfb['Unnamed: 25'] != ' ')],
            }.get(argument, f"{logging.warning(f'{argument} not found in specified variables')}")
```

...returns this...

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9vKr.png)

The output returns the default argument even though the switch-case argument was successful, given that it did return the pandas Data frame.

So how can I make it so it only appears when it wasn't found, as it should if it were just a string and not a logging-string method.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python evaluates the arguments for the arguments to a function before it calls the function. That's why your logging function will get called regardless of the result of `get()`. Another thing is your f-string is probably going to evaluate to `"None"` every time since `logging.warning()` doesn't return anything, which doesn't seem like what you intended. You should just handle this with a regular if statement like

```
variables = {
    'fb': data.loc[0:99, :].reset_index(),
    ...
}
if argument in variables:
    return variables[argument]
else:
    logging.warning(f'{argument} not found in specified variables')
```

Comment: your code was helpful at preventing the logging.warning() function to appear regardless of the results. You were also right about the returned 'None'. It comes up when the argument isnt in the dictionary along with the logging warning....

***None \n
process_variables :: notdict not found in specified variables.***

is none just naturally there because there is a return statement under the IF argument?

Comment: Any function which exits without explicitly returning anything will return `None`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think i got it. An else statement - which supposedly returns something - returns none because techincally there isnt anything explicit other than the 'implicit' loging function inside it. That makes sense to me.